# Send email with PhpMailer without waiting for return

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using [PhpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to send e-mails. It's working fine.

But in some cases I don't want to wait for the send function to return, specially because it can take a while sometimes. I just want to send and finish the funcition right away.

Is it possible to achieve this?

This is a sample code I'm using (nothing different from the basics).

```
try {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    // ...other options...
    $mail->send();

    return true;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return $e;
}
```

Comment: you'll need to wait for it, unless you call the script via ajax

Comment: I think the only way to avoid that is to implement a queue, send the jobs there and have a worker pick-up pending jobs.

Comment: It seems like this could be done by putting the email sending onto a different thread with something like https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use ajax or configure your own queueing system to do this. Just use a local mail server - which implicitly has a built-in queueing system that you don't need to configure - and you can submit messages to it in a fraction of a second. There is some performance advice [on the PHPMailer wiki](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Sending-to-lists).

Comment: Would you mind explain (with example) how to do it? The application I'm working on is hosted on a shared hosting service and it's used only for single e-mail. Ex.: Welcome email, when a purchase is made, to recover password, etc..

Comment: You need to check with your ISP. They probably block direct outbound SMTP, but should allow you to submit via a local mail server - see if you can send using `isSMTP()` and `Host = 'localhost'` or `isMail()`. Shared hosting is a worst-case scenario though, it's very restrictive and you shouldn't expect anything to go particularly fast, nor to be able to install a proper queueing system.

Answer (score 0):

Like jeroen mentioned, you should use queues to achieve this. If you ever configured the cron to work with PHP, this have the similar principle except that it doesn't repeat the same task by schedule but executes any task you provide one-by-one in a queue. You can even give priorities to these tasks. I suggest you to start with beanstalkd.